# Javascript clearInterval not reseting countdown value

Tags: javascript, countdown, clearinterval, swiper.js

I'm making a swiper slider. My goal is to have a countdown that reset's its value every slide change. If slides changes automatically the countdown reset's well and starts counting down again on next slide.
The problem is that if i click on the navigation dots then i have some sort of double countdown. I think clearInterval starts another countdown but the previous countdowns are not removed from the thread execution.

```
var autoplay = 20000;
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: true,
    watchSlidesProgress: true,
    autoplay: 20000,
    onProgress: elipse
});

function elipse() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    var countdownNumberEl = document.getElementById('countdown-number');
    var countdown = 20;
    countdownNumberEl.textContent = countdown;
    var timer = setInterval(frame, 1000);
    function frame(){
        countdown = --countdown <= 0 ? 20 : countdown;
        countdownNumberEl.textContent = countdown;
    }
}

var swiperBullet = document.getElementsByClassName("swiper-pagination-bullet");
for (var i = 0; i < swiperBullet.length; i++) {
    swiperBullet[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        elipse();
    });
}
```

Can somebody help me resolve what is going on?

Comment: Your variable `timer` is only available in the scope of the `elipse` function.

Comment: Bu if i change scope of timer variable the result is the same. I have already tried that.

Comment: Your `clearInterval` is not in a  function or anything. It is executed before your `elipse` function ever initiates the interval.

Comment: clearInterval is called when i click on a navigation dot to move some slide to the next or previous slide. it is inside a click eventListener.

Comment: I moved it to elipse function as suggested by CBroe. But the result is the same.

Comment: @AndréCastro declare timer before `elipse()` and change `var timer = setInterval(frame, 1000);` to `timer = setInterval(frame, 1000);`

Comment: A variable only exists in a scope while that scope is active. Every invocation of `elipse`, `timer` will be a new variable with no knowledge of the previous invocation.

Comment: It is OK now. Many thanks @angel.bonev. The problem was timer was not global. Solved. Also many thanks to all who contributed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `timer` is still not declared and it's undefined

```js
function elipse() {
    //timer will be undefined or throw error that is not declared
    //so you are not clearing anything
    console.log(timer);
    clearInterval(timer);
    //stuff

    //this wil redaclare timer every time you enter the function and it will return different intervalID
    //so this will grow exponentially
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        elipse()
    }, 1000);
}
elipse()
```

So you must declare `timer` out of the scope for function `elipse` it's not necessary to be a global variable just out of the scope for example:

```js
(function () {
  var timer;
  function elipse() {
      //only the first time will be undefined
      console.log(timer);
      clearInterval(timer);
      //just don't redeclared timer becouse it will be for this scope and it will create a new intervalID that you can't access
      timer = setInterval(function () {
          elipse()
      }, 1000);
  }
  elipse()
})();
```

> P.S. [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) expects intervalID
>
> > The identifier of the repeated action you want to cancel. This ID was returned by the corresponding call to [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).
>
> And `setInterval` **Return value** is *a numeric, non-zero value*
>
> So in my opinion `undefined` won't cause troubles

Answer (score 1):

Make `timer` a global variable, so it won't forget its value by the time you try to use it (local variables do not keep their value, so when you call a function again, `timer` starts as `undefined`). Perhaps make the clear conditional, so it doesn't try stopping a timer when there is none (the first call):

```
var timer=false;
function elipse() {
  if(timer !== false) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
  [...]
  timer = setInterval(frame, 1000);
```

Comment: You have my upvote but why do you need to check `if(timer !== false) {` don't think that `intervalID` will ever be `false`

Comment: @angel.bonev when the function is called the first time ever, there is no timer running. Just by looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval I can't decide if providing an invalid identifier to `clearInterval()` should really work in all environments, though it's probably okay for browsers.

Comment: Yeah they say **However, for clarity, you should avoid doing so.**